# Magento 2 Allowed Memory exhausted error when compile code

Tags: php, magento-2.0, memory, code-generation

I have error when i add module..

**Please re-run Magento compile command**

so i run below command but also display error that below when run command from root,

**php magento setup:di:compile**

```
Compilation was started.
%message% 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% 1 sec 37.0 MiB%message% 0/7 [>
---------------------------]   0% 1 sec 37.0 MiBProxies code generation... 0/7 [
>---------------------------]   0% 1 sec 37.0 MiB
Proxies code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 47 secs 43.5
MiB
Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 47 secs
43.5 MiB
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
 24 bytes) in D:\xampp\htdocs\linsenwelt\vendor\zendframework\zend-code\src\Scan
ner\FileScanner.php on line 36
```

How to fix ?

Comment: I'm getting same error in live server

Answer (score 101, accepted):

A quick solution for memory limit in Magento 2 command is directly adding memory limit inside command.

For Compilation command,

```
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

For Deployment

```
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

You can change as per 5G to max if issue not resolve.

Comment: thanks @rakesh it saves my time thank you very much once again

Comment: Take care, increasing memory limit can be only a temporary solution.

Comment: Isnt like 5G an incredible amount of MEM ... and is this M2 related or more composer related ... it feels quiet silly to give 5G's RAM ... to composer ... what is it used for?

Answer (score 15):

use this 'dirty' way

```
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 8):

Looks like your cli has only 128MB of memory allocated. Increase the value to at least 256MB or 512MB if you can.

Comment: I tried 512mb size for my php.ini file but still not work...how solve ?

Comment: If you still get `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes` then you didn't increase the memory limit for cli.

Comment: In which file i set memory limit ??

Answer (score 7):

```
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using PHP >= 5.3.0 and you used the Magento 2.1.x and above, then after you run `composer install`, two files will be created in your root directory and your pub directory named `.user.ini`

Edit those files to override your PHP.ini settings, in this case is the `memory_limit`

```
; Set PHP memory limit to 768M which already enough for compilation tasks
memory_limit = 768M
max_execution_time = 18000
```

If you are using Apache, you will need to care the files inside root directory only, not the `/pub` one and vice versa if you are using engineX (nginx)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You need to increase memory allocated to php. To increase memory, execute command `php --ini` . Findout loaded php.ini. It should be like

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini,
```

Go to current loaded php.ini (/etc/php5/cli/php.ini) and findout memory_limit parameter. Increase the value against memory_limit parameter to 256M or 512M.

Answer (score 3):

This situation can be tricky to debug since if you just to

```
php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"
```

it shows the memory limit for the PHP in your path, which might be fine.  But the magento script (bin/magento) uses the preamble

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

so it is not necessarily using the PHP from your path!  One way to track down the `php.ini` file which is being used is to write a small script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
phpinfo();
```

call it `getinfo` (not `getinfo.php`!), make it executable, then run it like this:

```
./getinfo  | grep php.ini
```

This will show you the ini file you need to change.  In that file, change the configuration value `memory_limit` as suggested in other posts, to a higher value than 128M.  Then save the file and check your work:

```
./getinfo  | grep memory_limit
```

Answer (score 2):

I run into similar problem, memory limit was increased to 2Gb inside php ini file, phpinfo() file showed it was set to 2Gb. It seems Magento set memory limit manually somewhere. I increased memory limit inside file bin/magento. In first line I put this:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '656M');
```

which made it working.

Answer (score 2):

I have got solution for my question. For memory exhausted error, we have to add memory limit for compile code.

```
php -dmemory_limit=4G bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

**Hope it will help someone in future.**

Answer (score 1):

> 67

A quick solution for memory limit in Magento 2 command is directly adding memory limit inside command.

For Compilation command,

```
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

For Deployment

```
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

You can change as per 5G to max if issue not resolve.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the EXACT same issue. It's a combination of RAM and PHP version. I have to call
/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin php -d memory_limit=3G bin/magento setup:di:compile (or flush, etc)

Answer (score 0):

User the following line after 
`php/bin magento -d memory_limit=5G s:d:c`
 for your compilation code. This is due the allowed memory limit to the php. But after allowing the memory limit in the command  this will remove the error and your compilation and other commands will run without any error. Just add this 
`-d memory_limit=5G`
in every command as you seen in the example above.
Upvote if you found my answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

Compilation using "-d memory_limit=5G" is not a wise decision. It's a temporary solution which may get affected during the process of Mode Switching i.e from Developer to Production. This time the system compiles the code without this logic "-d memory_limit=5G" which throws the error.

It's a better option to fix this error at this stage. To fix this, open php.ini and increase the memory_limit by 1024M and execute compile command php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Check this: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors

This time it should work

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue in the cli, please try This command:

```
php -dmemory_limit=8G bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

for M2 add memory limit via ssh with below command.

for compile command : `php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile`
for deploy command :  `php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

you can increase value 5G if issue not solved.

Answer (score 0):

I use Plesk and I solved the issue run next command :

-bash-4.2$ `/opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php -d memory_limit=3G bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Note than 7.3 is my PHP release, instead you should apply your current PHP release.

Comment: Now my PLesk > cron job show same error PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes). Maybe I edited something else ? Whatever I try to apply same method but do not works for me /opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php -d memory_limit=3G /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/subdomain.mydomain.com/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1   Any help I will apreciatte

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WAMP, the folder `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php<your-version>` contains two php ini files: `php.ini` and `phpForApache.ini`

Look for `memory_limit` option and set to afford your needs, I set mine to 9999M in *both files*.

Hope it helps