# How to run deploy command while memory exhausted and we can't able to increase server memory limit?

Tags: magento-2.1, deploy, memory

Sever memory exhausted while run content deploy command and sever memory can't be increase then how to run content deploy command?

Comment: Duplicate question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92492/magento-2-allowed-memory-exhausted-error-when-compile-code

Answer (score 3):

Before posting a question on Stack Exchange, please have a little look around first, you'll often find the question has already been asked/answered. Maybe just asked in a slightly different way.

See the answer from this post: [Fatal error "Allowed memory size" while run setup:static-content:deploy](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97749/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-while-run-setupstatic-contentdeploy)

For clarity, i think what you're looking for is (taken from post mentioned above) you can set the memory limit inline whilst running the static content deploy command:

```
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. By this reason i can't do upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Please try below command

```
php bin/magento  c:c

php bin/magento  setup:upgrade

php -d memory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php -d memory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Hope it works!

Answer (score 1):

Use below command to set server limit just add below code in any of the command if you have any server memory limit error.

```
-dmemory_limit=6g
```

like below command check.

```
php -dmemory_limit=10g bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 1):

Deploy only themes you need, example:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/blank --theme Magento/luma
```