# Magento2 : How To Solve Out Of Memory Limit Error While Using Composer Update Command

Tags: magento2, composer, memory

[image]

I got out of memory error while run "composer update" command,
I already check memory_limit and that is 2048 M than also  I am getting above error
.
Does anyone know how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92492/magento-2-allowed-memory-exhausted-error-when-compile-code you can try it.

Comment: i already do all that things but getting same error

Answer (score 7):

Try full path to composer

`whereis composer`

Once you know path

`php -d memory_limit=4G /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer update -vvv`

Answer (score 2):

You can try below command

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer update
```

**Hope this will help you!!**

Comment: yes tried but getting same error

Comment: can you check the server space once, that may be making problem for you.

Comment: Have same problem. Did you guys fix this?

Comment: Why would a simple program need soooooo much MEM ...

Answer (score 1):

This is the way you can write composer command and it will resolve the issue.

```
php -dmemory_limit=5G composer update
```

Thanks

Comment: i already tried but getting same error

Answer (score 1):

You can try edit value memory_limit in php.ini file.

Comment: yes i already check and it is 2048 M than also gettting same error

Comment: Try a larger value.