# Magento Upgrade 2.2.8 to 2.3.3

Tags: magento2

When I am running this command on my local system 
`composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.3.3`
I am getting this error:

> Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>   134217736 bytes)

in p

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/291432/70343 although instead of `composer update` `composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.3.3`

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add "-d memory_limit=5G" to your query. Is it okay?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/168172)

Comment: @MohitKumarArora why does this not provide an answer? I  though the asker was missing a part in his query and I just suggested him to add it into the code. what's wrong?

Comment: may be you can provide some detail.